# Fatal error: uncaught error: función name must be a string

Tags: php, array, mysqli

Estoy elaborando un login, mi código primer código me funciona bien, pero pues me gustaría poder mostar algunos campos de fila con una variable simple o incluso insertarlos en variables SESSION y he ahí donde entra mi segundo código donde he estado teniendo el error del título...
Primer codigo(el que me funciona):

```
<?php
include("../ebd/db1.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
}
if(isset($_POST['contraseña'])){
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
}
$_SESSION['susuario'] = $_POST['usuario'];
$tabla = 'usuarios';

$sql = "SELECT nusuario, contraseña FROM `$tabla` WHERE nusuario = '$usuario' AND contraseña = '$contraseña'";

$consulta = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sql);

$rows = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

if($rows >= 1 ){
$_SESSION['incio'] = time();
$_SESSION['expiro'] = $_SESSION['incio'] + (1 * 60);

echo '<script  type="text/javascript"> 
alert("¡Credenciales validas! Se ingresó con exito!"); 
</script>';   
echo "<p class='lgnw'><b>Bienvenido !</b></p>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=../index.html'>";
}
else {
echo "<p class='lgnw'><b>Contraseña y/o usuario invalido</b></p>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5;url=indexlgn.html'>";
}

mysqli_free_result($consulta);
mysqli_close($enlacebd);
?>
```

Este es mi segundo código con el que he estado teniendo el problema del título:

```
<?php
include("../ebd/db1.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
}
if(isset($_POST['contraseña'])){
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
}
$_SESSION['susuario'] = $_POST['usuario'];
$tabla = 'usuarios';


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$tabla` WHERE nusuario = '$usuario' AND contraseña = '$contraseña'";

$consulta = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sql);

if($consulta(num_rows >= 1)){

$row = $consulta(fetch_array(mysqli_assoc));
$nombre = $row[nombre];

mysqli_free_result($consulta);
mysqli_close($enlacebd);
echo '<script  type="text/javascript"> 
alert("¡Credenciales validas! Se ingresó con exito!"); 
</script>';   
echo "<p class='lgnw'><b>Bienvenido ".$nombre."!</b></p>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=../index.html'>";
}
else {
echo "<p class='lgnw'><b>Contraseña y/o usuario invalido</b></p>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=indexlgn.html'>";
}

?>
```

He estado aprendiendo de esto empiricamente por si se llega a notar algun error que yo no veo, la sintaxis o algo.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Tu código está plagado de errores: de concatenación, de funciones mal llamadas, de no respeto de la convención de nombres. Por ejemplo, es `include` no `Incluye`. Debes cuidar de abrir y cerrar bien las concatenaciones con comillas. Debes escribir los nombres de funciones en minúscula: `session_start(), if, echo` etc. Si empiezas con comilla simples no puedes terminar con comillas dobles, como ocurre aquí: `$tabla= 'usuarios";` ponlo así: `$tabla= "usuarios";`

Comment: No, lo que pasa es que lo transcribi desde el teléfono y cambia mucho las palabras el autocorrector...  Si es error por una palabra mal escrita probablemente haya sido el corrector, intente modificar alguna que note, pero no me fijé en todas... En la ejecución del código todos esos errores no estan

Comment: Pon tu código original por favor, como está ahora es imposible analizarlo, si observas es desastroso.

Comment: Si empiezas con comillas simples, debes terminar con comillas simples. Error aquí: `$tabla= 'usuarios";` prueba así: **`$tabla= 'usuarios';`**

Comment: Ese error te da por que ademas de lo que ya te menciono @A.Cedano estas mandando a llamar una función muy mal en esta parte :  **$consulta(num_rows >= 1)**  es como si llamaras a una funcion que contiene la variable **$consulta** la cual tiene un objeto y por eso el error dice que tiene que ser un string el nombre de la función.. y asi otra vez unas lineas abajo ... realmente no se por que lo haces así, si unas lineas arriba utilizas correctamente la función:  **mysqli_num_rows()**

Comment: Ya coloque coloque el codigo desde una PC, ahora si se muestra el codigo como realmente esta

Comment: Tienes tremendo lío con el estilo procedurlar de `mysqli`, tienes cambiar las llamadas, por ejemplo tendrías que ponerlo asi: `if ( mysqli_num_rows($consulta) >= 1 ) {` y  obtener la fila así: `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)`

Comment: Listo, problema resuelto, estaba bloqueado y me puse a buscar y modificar sin sentido, muchas gracias!

Comment: En la parte inferior hay una caja de texto que dice "Tu Respuesta", agrega el código que te ha resultado a partir de esta conversación entre comentarios y luego de 24 horas márcala como aceptada, estarás colaborando con la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas) y también serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan un problema similar al planteado :D

Comment: Ok, ya lo agrego (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solucion al codigo antes mostrado arriba era al momento de llamar las funciones mysqli_num_rows y mysqli_fetch_assoc() de todos modos ya veran el orden que realmente va, fijandose en el codigo defectuoso y este, gracias a los que aportaron un poco de su tiempo (y)

```
<?php
include("../ebd/db1.php");
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['usuario'])){
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
}
if(isset($_POST['contraseña'])){
$contraseña = $_POST['contraseña'];
}
$_SESSION['susuario'] = $_POST['usuario'];
$tabla = 'usuarios';


$sql = "SELECT * FROM `$tabla` WHERE nusuario = '$usuario'";

$consulta = mysqli_query($enlacebd,$sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($consulta) >= 1){

$row = (mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta));
$nombre = $row['nombre'];

mysqli_free_result($consulta);
mysqli_close($enlacebd);
echo '<script  type="text/javascript"> 
alert("¡Credenciales validas! Se ingresó con exito!"); 
</script>';   
echo "<p class='lgnw'><b>Bienvenido ".$nombre."!</b></p>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=../index.html'>";
}
else {
echo "<p class='lgnw'><b>Contraseña y/o usuario invalido</b></p>";
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=indexlgn.html'>";
}

?>
```